# SAP B1 9.2 Webservice - PHP - (OrdersService Method GetByParams)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, sapb1

I get an Error when try to consume a webservice of SAP B1 9.2 (OrdersService->GetByParams):

> env:Sender-Unknown SOAP Command

I can get login, logout and call Update method from OrdersService.wsdl without problem.
This is my code for call OrdersService->GetByParams method.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try{
    $OrdersService = new GetByParams("http://shockwave/B1WS/WebReferences/OrdersService.wsdl");
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://shockwave/B1WS/Service.asmx','SessionID', '3A8F8F0E-D114-4F6B-8BCC-509F55F4406F');
    $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://shockwave/B1WS/Service.asmx','ServiceName','OrdersService');
    $OrdersService->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
    $parametros =array('DocEntry'=>'2390');
    $respuesta = $OrdersService->GetByParams($parametros);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
    $error = 1; 
    print(" <h1>Error, idiota<br> ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring); 
    echo "<br>Request: \n".htmlspecialchars($OrdersService->__getLastRequest()) ."\n"; 
    echo "<br>Response: \n".htmlspecialchars($OrdersService->__getLastResponse())."\n";
}

class GetByParams extends SoapClient { 
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null) {
        $namespace = "http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS";
        $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1 xmlns="'.$namespace.'"', $request, 1); 
        $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1', $request); 
        $request = str_replace(array('/ns1:', 'xmlns:ns1="'.$namespace.'"'), array('/', ''), $request); 
        $request = preg_replace('/UTF-8/', 'UTF-16', $request, 1); 
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null); 
    } 
}

// <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="OrdersService" xmlns:ns2="http://shockwave/B1WS/Service.asmx">
    // <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        // <ns2:SessionID>3A8F8F0E-D114-4F6B-8BCC-509F55F4406F</ns2:SessionID>
        // <ns2:ServiceName>OrdersService</ns2:ServiceName>
    // </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    // <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        // <ns1:GetByParams/>
    // </SOAP-ENV:Body>
// </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

?>
```

Code Login:

```
$LoginService = new LoginSoap("http://XXXXX/B1WS/WebReferences/LoginService.wsdl");
    echo "<pre>";
    $options = array(
                    'DatabaseServer' => 'shockwave',
                    'DatabaseName' => 'XXXX',
                    'DatabaseType' => 'XXXX',
                    'CompanyUsername' => 'XXXX',
                    'CompanyPassword' => 'XXXX',
                    'Language' => 'ln_Spanish',
                    'LicenseServer' => 'XXXX:30000',
                    );
$LoginId = $respuesta->SessionID;
unset($LoginService);

    //Logueamos
    $respuesta = $LoginService->Login($options);
    echo "Login ...<br><h1>Logueado ID: ".$respuesta->SessionID."</h1>";
```

Code LogOut:

```
//LogOut
$respuesta = $LoginService->Logout($LoginId);
echo "<br>Logout ... ";
echo '<h1>Deslogueado';
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Another info: I can get the document using GetByParams on SoapUI, without errors in a simple XML call.